# Symfony 2.8 REST API: authenticate with token and user session

Tags: symfony, session, authentication, access-token, symfony-2.8

I have a WebApp that use FosUserBundle for Login with Username/Passwd in the GUI and authenticate against the REST API with GuardAuthenticator (stateless) with a token in http header.

Now i will use REST API functions from within the WebApp GUI via ajax. But not every user have an API Token.

Is it possible to get a existing User Session in the GuardAuthenticator and use it for authentication against the REST API?

Answer (score 0):

The Rest API is now under different Routes:

Routing:

```
MyApiBundle:
  resource: "@MyApiBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  type:     rest
  prefix:   /{apiroot}
  defaults:
    - apiroot: api
  requirements:
    apiroot:  ^api|apii$
```

And FOS Rest is enabled for both:

```
fos_rest:
  zone:
    - { path: ^/api/* }
    - { path: ^/apii/* }
```

The first one ( /api/* ) is protected with a GuardAuthenticator and second one ( /apii/* ) is protected with FOS User for internal use.